# Can I take a ref to part of std::string inside a loop and have it available outside?

Tags: c++

I am parsing a std::string in a function which takes the string as a `const std::string&` parameter, and it is useful for me to take the whole rest of the string after I encounter a space. I want to store a reference to the tail of the string at that stage and use it to avoid copying the string.

I have a switch statement inside a for loop iterating over the string, and I will need to take the ref in one of the `case` labels. The problem is that you can't re-assign to a reference AFAIK, and declaring the ref inside the case is also illegal. Furthermore, I need the ref outside the switch as well.

Here is a simplified example:

```cpp
#include <string>

bool isValid(const std::string &s)
{
    unsigned int length {s.length()};
    for (unsigned int i {0}; i < length; ++i)
    {
        switch s[i]
        {
            // whatever other cases
            case ' ':
                const std::string &tail {s.substr(i, length - i};
                break;
            default:
                // whatever
        }
        if (tail == "abcd")
            // do something
    }
}
```

I don't know exactly what should happen, because I am pretty much a C++ newbie, but I just want to save the cost of a copy and allocation on the heap if I don't use a ref.

Comment: Can you use C++17 features?

Comment: What if the string does not contain a space at all?

Comment: @L.F. that isn't a problem. Then the case just doesn't ever execute ;-)

Comment: The simpler solution is to store the index you want and construct the substring after the loop if you found anything.

Comment: @lubgr I think so. I have both mingw with at least C++14 and Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @molbdnilo the use of the tail is still inside the loop, just outside the switch

Comment: @LouisCloete OK, after the switch, then. The principle is still the same.

Comment: @molbdnilo So I need a bool flag I can switch from false to true inside the case and then ref the substring afterwards depending on if the flag is true or not?

Comment: @LouisCloete Or you can default the index to `length-1`, which will give you an empty substring later. (With C++17, you would use `std::string_view` instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to store a reference to the tail of the string at that stage and use it to avoid copying the string.

A reference is an alias for an object, so there is no such thing as a reference to a part of a `std::string` object. You can either create a new sub-string, e.g. with `std::string::substr` as you posted it:

```
const std::string &tail {s.substr(i, length - i};
```

Note that this is valid as `const`-qualified references extends the lifetime of a temporary, here the return value of `s.substr(...)`, but weird.

A cleaner way would be to pass a `std::string_view` in the first place, which is exactly tailored for such a use case, and use `std::string_view::substr` to extract new views on parts of the strings. This is much more efficient (as no buffer must be copied) and idiomatic.

```
#include <string_view>

bool isValid(const std::string_view &s)
{
    // ...

    const std::string_View tail = s.substr(i, length - i);

}
```

Comment: So I could use a `const std::string_view` everywhere I want to pass a `std::string` efficiently as a function parameter in a read-only fashion?

Comment: As long as you can assure that the lifetime of the string that the `std::string_view` instance is a view on persists the scope of e.g. a function.

Comment: So if I have a string in a function and then I pass a view onto that string as parameter to another function, it would pass the constraints you laid out, right?

Comment: Yes. I recommend [this blogpost](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/03/27/string-view-is-a-borrow-type/) on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to store a reference to the tail of the string

`std::string &` is a reference to a string. It is not a reference to a part of a string.

This is what `std::string_view` is for:

```
const std::string_view tail =
    std::string_view(s).substr(i, std::string_view::npos);
```

Prior to C++17, you could simply use a pair of iterators:

```
auto substr_beg = s.begin() + i;
auto substr_end = s.end();
```